# Same R code not working with 2 different .csv files but same data structure

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

Hi I have 2 pieces of code, they are doing the same, one is using a dataset that comes with R, the other a .csv file that I have created, nothing on the code has changed other than more columns on the .csv file with different names, but for some reason I am getting a wrong output

the csv file for this code is located here
https://github.com/juandavidlozano/Data_1/blob/main/high_northell.csv

this is the first code

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(repr)

dat <- economics

drops <- c("date")
dat <- dat[ , !(names(dat) %in% drops)]


cols = c('pce', 'pop', 'psavert', 'uempmed')

pre_proc_val <- preProcess(dat[,cols], method = c("center", "scale"))


dat[,cols] = predict(pre_proc_val, dat[,cols])




###### Linear Regression


number_days = 10

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
new_cols <- c('Intercept', paste0(cols, '_predict'))
dat[new_cols] <- NA

inds <- nrow(dat) - number_days




dat[(number_days+1):nrow(dat), new_cols] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(inds), function(x) {
  lr = lm(unemploy ~ uempmed + psavert + pop + pce, data = dat[x:(x + number_days - 1), ])
  t(lr$coefficients)
}))
```

the `dat` dataframe looks like this

[image]

the first 10 rows have some NA's that is because of the variable `number_days` it leaves the first X rows empty and from there it fills it with the coefficients of a linear regression model for the last X days of data and so on.

this dataframe is correct, all the column have values.

the second code is this one

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(repr)

dat<-read.csv("high_northell.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

drops <- c("date")
dat <- dat[ , !(names(dat) %in% drops)]


cols = c("state_covid_death","kantar_state_tv_daily","VIX", "interest_urgent_care","CPI","SPY",                       
         "kantar_state_digital_daily", "Flu_indicator","covid_cases",               
         "Search.Cost","Display.Cost")

pre_proc_val <- preProcess(dat[,cols], method = c("center", "scale"))


dat[,cols] = predict(pre_proc_val, dat[,cols])




###### Linear Regression

number_days = 10

dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
new_cols <- c('Intercept', paste0(cols, '_predict'))
dat[new_cols] <- NA

inds <- nrow(dat) - number_days

dat[(number_days+1):nrow(dat), new_cols] <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(inds), function(x) {
  lr = lm(Total.Visits~ state_covid_death + kantar_state_tv_daily + VIX+    interest_urgent_care+   CPI+    SPY +kantar_state_digital_daily+    Flu_indicator   + covid_cases+  Search.Cost+    Display.Cost, data = dat[x:(x + number_days - 1), ])
  t(lr$coefficients)
}))
```

As you can see is the same code but the `dat` dataframe in this case for some reason some columns are filled with NA's and some are filled NA's and data here and there, this data frame should look like the one at top, all columns should be filled except for the first X rows.

here is a pic data dataframe for this second code

[image]

Any help on what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear regression fails to define some variables due to singularities.

For a given 10 day subset those variables are constant across all days, thus those variables are perfectly multicollinear and the X'X matrix is singular.